# how solve the inequality $−1\leq \leq1$?

Tags: inequality

How can we solve this equation graphically ? why we talk about the two hyperbole $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{-1}{x}$ ?
I divided this equation on two sub-equations $$ xy\leq1$$ and  $$xy\geq-1$$.

For the first sub-equation  I have two cases when x is greater or not than zero. Also for the second I have two other equations depending if $x \geq0$ or not.

That said, I no longer know how to solve my system of 4 sub equations

Comment: Maybe it becomes clearer if you think geometrically, in terms of the level sets of the function $f(x,y)=xy$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be written compactly as $|xy| \le 1$. The region is symmetrical about $x$-axis and $y$-axis due to the absolute value.

Clearly $x=0$ and $y=0$ are part of the  solution.

If $x \ne 0$, then we have $|y| \le \frac1{|x|}$

In the first quadrant, it is below the line $y=\frac1x$. The other cases can be obtained by using symmetry.

In the fourth quadrant, it is above $y=-\frac1x$.

In the second quadrant, it is below $y=-\frac1x$.

In the third quadrant, it is above $y=\frac1x$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by cases, we have that

- for $x>0$

$$−1\leq \leq1 \iff -\frac1x \le y \le \frac1x$$

- for $x<0$ (direction of inequalities flip)

$$−1\leq \leq1 \iff \frac1x \le y \le -\frac1x$$

and for $x=0 \implies xy=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the solutions is delimited by the two hyperbolas $xy=-1$ and $xy=1$ (each with two branches).

These partition the plane in five regions, one being a "cross" in the middle. As $(0,0)$ is a solution, the whole cross, including boundaries, is the solution set. (There cannot be solutions on the "other side" of a boundary.)